# How to change plot range in plot function

Tags: plotting

I have a function $y=f(x)$ which I want to be shown in a domain $0<x<10$
and $6<y<10$. How could I do that? I can change the x domain in Plot function but I don't know how to change y-axis?

Comment: Take a look at `PlotRange`.

Comment: I looked at it but examples are 3dplot @Kuba

Comment: [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) not true.

Comment: @saranj It's okay to ask questions here - that's what stack exchange is made for - but people around here appreciate some minimal effort when asking a question. Consider reading some documentation (especially the `Options`-section of some function that you want to use) and take a few minutes to familiarize yourself the [usage guidelines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) of this community.

Comment: I will do that @Sascha

Comment: @Kuba How can I divide y-axis by a number in ListContourPlot?

Comment: I thing it's better to ask it. Because there is not such a questions in site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the help of Kuba,

```
Plot[f,{x,0,10},PlotRange -> {6, 10}]
```